# I want to add facility to add country, State, City in my custom plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am working on a plugin for trip adviser, In that i am to add service for user that he can add country, state, city in which his company provides the trips.
What should i prefer for that, Please suggest me some effective things or links.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please rephrase.

Comment: @Sisir  I want to give facility to a user that he can add trips. Also he can select the location of trip. for that i have to give the facilities to add the locations as like country and state. so there will be another menu to add country and states in my plugin. 
For that i need support that what should i do in my Plugin

Comment: Add the description to the main question by file an [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/158609/edit). Also you might want to look at [`add_menu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page)

Comment: @sisir I will upload it within few minutes